# Gradle include outside resource including the containing folder

Tags: java, gradle

I am converting a project built with Ant to use Gradle. The project looks something like

```
root
|-RelevantProject
...
|-LotsOfOtherSubprojects
...
|-Resources
|--resources
|---subfolder
|----bunchOfProps.properties
```

The code references these as `Resources/resources/subfolder/bunchOfProps.properties`. This code and the folder structure cannot be changed as the ant scripts need to keep functioning

I have attempted to include this as

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir '../Resources'
        }
    }
}
```

Which fails as the code top level folder is now cut off. The code would work if looking for `resources/subfolder/bunchOfProps.properties`.

I have also attempted `compile files('../Resources')` with the same problem. Hard to say as this one did not appear in the Build directory. `compile fileTree(dir: '../', include: '**/*.properties')`, which I hoped would just pick up the relevant files also did not show up in the build directory.

Simply using the root directory as a resource folder caused problems as it included other projects and even the .gradle directory. I haven't yet gotten it to compile this way. Not sure yet if I can exclude enough things to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just need to copy the files

```
ext.prjRoot = project.projectDir.toString()

task copyExtResources(type: Copy) {
    from prjRoot
    include "Resources/**"
    into "$buildDir/resources/main"
}

processResources.dependsOn copyExtResources
```

Answer (score 1):

[PrasadU's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62708869/1703730) is sort-of correct, but it breaks up-to-date checking as it introduces a task where the output overlaps with the one from `processResources`. It is better to just reconfigure the latter task instead:

```
processResources {
    from(projectDir) {
        include("Resources/**")
    }
}
```